# Substring an XML Columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to substring an xml column for the first time. Below is one line from the xml column. I need to substring per DRN, Date, Amount. Sometimes there can be more than one instance in one row. how will i substring this?

```
<ITEMS><ITEM SEQ="0" INDNO="50814" DRN="N00230000004816012012" CR_GUID="FB64CD73-8048-4775-81F2-969AE2AB442C" DR_GUID="8025D121-E3B6-4479-A393-CDDC5BEB53C0" CR_ACC="" DR_ACC="" AMOUNT="0" DATE="20120202" /></ITEMS>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please consider reworking your question to be more clear and use more precise terminology?

Comment: Hi sure, i need to only get for example the number: N00230000004816012012 from the xml column. But i have instances where DRN=number can occur more than once in the same line and i need to display both in the report. i am not sure how to substring my SQL query to get this. I can get it if it occurs only once. this is the first time i have to do a substring like this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `substring` you use the [xml Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/184d0/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  XMLColumn xml
)

insert into YourTable values
('<ITEMS><ITEM SEQ="0" INDNO="50814" DRN="N00230000004816012012" CR_GUID="FB64CD73-8048-4775-81F2-969AE2AB442C" DR_GUID="8025D121-E3B6-4479-A393-CDDC5BEB53C0" CR_ACC="" DR_ACC="" AMOUNT="0" DATE="20120202" /></ITEMS>')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select I.N.value('@DRN', 'varchar(50)') as DRN
from YourTable as T
  cross apply T.XMLColumn.nodes('/ITEMS/ITEM') as I(N)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/184d0/1/0)**:

```
|                   DRN |
-------------------------
| N00230000004816012012 |
```

Comment: Hi, may just ask one more thing, is I want to see for examle AMOUNT="0" AND Date="201202020" do i use the same syntax?

Comment: @user1854183 you just extend the field list `I.N.value('@AMOUNT', 'money') as Amount` etc.

Comment: `I.N.value('@DATE', 'Date') as Date`